Is [defrosting] the same as [thawing]?
If it is, I suggest merging / synonymizing defrosting and thawing since I don't have the rep on either tag...

Thank you for pointing this out.
While nobody has written an answer arguing for or against, I see that as of today, the question itself is at +4/-0 votes. So I went ahead and did the merge.
I chose to keep defrosting and remove thawing based on the frequency of usage - we had 89 questions tagged defrosting and 57 with thawing.

Awesome! I think defrosting is more well known to non-native english speakers
